# T SQL CASE WHEN EXISTS update statement

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql, case

having this currency conversion issue.  We have a table with exchange rates, and another with data to be updated.  Here is my query, which does not work because EX.currencyrate is not bound.  I just want to insert the rate from the rate table where applicable.

```
UPDATE #TMP_GT_PROCESSED_JDI_TST set FX_RATE_INVRS=
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (select basecurrencycode from  ExchangeRate EX
Join #TMP_GT_PROCESSED_JDI_TST TT
ON TT.currency=EX.basecurrencycode
AND EX.isactive=1)
then EX.currencyrate 
ELSE 0
END);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
UPDATE px
set px.FX_RATE_INVRS = isnull(EX.currencyrate,0)
from #TMP_GT_PROCESSED_JDI_TST px 
left join ExchangeRate EX on EX.basecurrencycode = px.currency
```

Comment: this looks like it turns the nulls into 0s, but it's not copying over the FX rates when NOT null.

Comment: If a record exists in the ExchangeRate table where the basecurrencycode field = currency field from #TMP_GT_PROCESSED_JDI_TST then #TMP_GT_PROCESSED_JDI_TST.FX_RATE_INVRS  will be set to ExchangeRate.currencyrate if the field is NOT NULL, or 0 if the field IS NULL.